# Osmnx: Removing sidewalk from one side of the street

Tags: python-2.7, gis, osmnx

I am trying to plot a simplified map for pedestrians in my university campus using Osmnx library with python 2.7.
So far, I have this [Image of the plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SRyU3.png) and as you can see, it is plotting sidewalks on both sides of the street. I was planning on removing one side of the sidewalks from this.

However I'm confused what logic to approach this with?

So far, I have created a custom filter to plot only footways

```
custom_walk = ('["area"!~"yes"]["highway"="footway"]["foot"!~"no"]["service"!~"private"]{}').format(ox.settings.default_access)

G = ox.graph_from_bbox(top, bottom,right, left, custom_filter= custom_walk)

ox.plot_graph(G_projected,save = True,filename = "maps", show = False,node_size=5,node_color='#FFFFFF',node_edgecolor='#FFFFFF',edge_color='#cccccc',bgcolor = "#000000",node_zorder=3,dpi=300, edge_linewidth=5,use_geom=True)

ox.simplify.clean_intersections(G,tolerance=100)
```

What I am trying to understand is does Osmnx have relations for footways in a way that will tell me their relative position to the nearest street (if they are on the east or the north side of the street (that way I can keep a standard on what sidewalks are visible)? Or if there is a simpler logic at this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What I am trying to understand is does Osmnx have relations for footways in a way that will tell me their relative position to the nearest street (if they are on the east or the north side of the street (that way I can keep a standard on what sidewalks are visible)? Or if there is a simpler logic at this?

The answer is no, OSMnx doesn't know where the sidewalk is in relation to the nearest street. One option might be to just identify the sidewalk edges you don't want, make a list of their OSM IDs, then remove them from the graph.